# Как правильно: "танцы с бубнами" или "танцы с бубном"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, жаргон

Как правильнее: "танцы с бубнами" или "танцы с бубном"?

Answer (score 2):

Танцы в натуре могут быть как с одним бубном, так и не с одним, - а как композитор с аранжировщиком положат. (Для сравнения погуглите танец с саблями - танец с саблей.)

Но прижился интернет-термин **[«танец с бубном»](http://www.internetslovar.ru/dictionary/700/)** - только в ед.ч.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> INTERNET slovar.ru

Словарь интернет-терминов,  жаргона и сокращений

> БУБЕН - обязательный реквизит сисадмина. Данный фольклорный элемент
>   берёт своё начало от фразы «танец с бубном», то есть совершение неких
>   телодвижений для достижения цели. Поскольку в работе администратора
>   никогда нельзя предсказать точно, будет ли сразу работать то или иное,
>   а также нельзя предвидеть набор всех возможных проблем и уж тем более,
>   набор решений этих проблем, считается, что они вынуждены постоянно
>   «танцевать с бубном». Особенно это относится к администрированию
>   программ от фирмы «1С».

**[подробности феномена](https://otvet.mail.ru/question/17891410)**

---

И [Викисловарь](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86%D1%8B_%D1%81_%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC) не возражает, но с пометой "шутл., сленг, неол., комп. жарг.": решение проблемы нестандартным и зачастую неформальным способом.

---

[«Танцевать с бубном»](http://fkn.ktu10.com/?q=node/9503) = шаманить.

> Часто, не желая тратить лишнее время, программисты и сисадмины просто
>   "бьют в бубен", решив проблему, например, переустановив какую-то
>   систему заново, так и не выяснив в чём там была причина (для
>   начинающих такое поведение -- вполне оправдано, ведь квалификации
>   чтобы разобраться часто не хватает, а учить "есть что и кроме этого").
>
> **Источник смысла**
>
> "Бубен" в выражении используется как отсылка к шаманам (в том смысле,
>   что они были людьми далёкими от технических наук).
>
> Изначально выражение исходит скорее из среды системных
>   администраторов, так как они больше используют "готовые" системы,
>   настраивая их, и далеко не всегда могут посмотреть исходный код, из-за
>   чего и приходится прибегать к странным приёмам.